# Filtering data in table in React based on values of radio buttons and input field after hitting submit failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have data from local json file that I use to create a table. 
In Table class component I have the table contains top 10 movies. The data is being displayed from filteredData state variable and are well displayed after loading the table. Above table I have 2 radio buttons, to choose whether I want to search data based on column title or column genre saved in state variable radioSearch by using function searchHandler. Then I have an input field, when I enter a string in it the result is being saved in searchFieldInput state variable, by using updatedSearch function.
Finally, I have submitHandler function in this component to filter the table based on selected radio button(title/genre of the film), and after that based on entered string in input field. The filtered data I am putting into filteredData variable in order to update the state by using setState. Unfortunately no filtering is being done after hitting submit. In Table component is nested TableRow component which should display the data based on applied filtering. I don't know whether the concept of submitHandler function is wrong, and why is not filtering the data? Can somebody help.
Here is my Table component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import TableRow from './TableRow/TableRow';

    class Table extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                filteredData: this.props.data,
                searchFieldInput: '',
                radioSearch: this.props.radioSearch,
                transformed: false
            }
        }

        updatedSearch = (event) => {
            this.setState({
                searchFieldInput: event.target.value
            })
        }

        searchHandler = (e) => {
            this.setState({
                radioSearch: e.target.value
            })
        };

        submitHandler = (event) => {

            event.preventDefault();

            if(this.state.radioSearch === "title") {
                let filteredData = this.props.data.filter(column => {
                    return column.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchFieldInput.toLowerCase()) !== -1; 
            }); 
                this.setState({
                    filteredData: filteredData
                });

                return this.state.filteredData;

            }   else if(this.state.radioSearch === "genre"){
                let filteredData = this.props.data.filter(column => {
                    return column.genre.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchFieldInput.toLowerCase()) !== -1; 
            });
                this.setState({
                    filteredData: filteredData
                });

                return this.state.filteredData;
            }

            console.log(this.state.radioSearch);
        }

        render() {

                let filteredData = this.props.data.filter(column => {
                    return column.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchFieldInput.toLowerCase()) !== -1; 
            }); 
            return(
                <React.Fragment>
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="container">
                            <form>
                                {/*Search field*/}  
                                <input
                                    className={"Search" + (this.state.transformed === true ?
                                            ' transformed' : '')} 
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder={(this.state.transformed === true ? 
                                    '' : 'Type here')}
                                    maxLength="20"
                                    value={this.state.searchFieldInput} required
                                    onChange={this.updatedSearch.bind(this)}
                                />

                                <button type="submit">
                                    Search
                                </button>

                                {/*Radio buttons*/}
                                <label htmlFor="title">
                                    <input type="radio" name="title" id="title" value="title" checked={this.state.radioSearch === "title"} 
                                    onChange={this.searchHandler}/>
                                    title
                                </label>
                                <label htmlFor="genre">
                                    <input type="radio" name="genre" id="genre" value="genre" checked={this.state.radioSearch === "genre"} 
                                    onChange={this.searchHandler}/>
                                    genre
                                </label> 
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div className="container">
                            <table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>No.</th>
                                        <th>Picture</th>
                                        <th>Release date</th>
                                        <th>Genre</th>
                                        <th>Rating</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                   {this.state.filteredData.map((row, index) => {
                                        return (
                                            <TableRow 
                                                numeration={index + 1}
                                                key={row.id} 
                                                row={row}
                                            />
                                        )
                                        })
                                    }
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>     
                </React.Fragment>
            )
        }
    }

    export default Table;
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Could you check the console. Also, you will need to bind all functions with `.bind(this)` either at constructor or at the place you are assigning it.

Comment: no error, data is just not being displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because you forgot to add the function to the submit button:

```
<button type="submit" onSubmit={this.submitHandler.bind(this)}>
  Search 
</button>
```

Comment: Added, but unfortunately nothing changed. No filtering, the table stays in same state  as when loaded first time.

Comment: Got it with this <button type="submit" onClick={event => this.submitHandler(event)}>     dabishan, thanks for the hint :)